# Warning message when cluster-argument is included in lavaan .06-2

Tags: clustering, lavaan

I have a sample of 529 people who are in 50 clusters. I'm not interested in any multilevel question but I would like to get cluster-robust standard errors for my SEM. Therefore, I included the cluster-argument in the lavaan function which is available now since the latest release.

The fit measures look great (as they also do when I do not include the cluster-argument) and the parameter estimates make sense (also they are similar to the estimates of the SEM without clustering). However, I keep getting this warning message:

> The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
>   does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
>   (= -5.998535e-19) is smaller than zero. This may be a symptom that
>   the model is not identified.

I was wondering why this happens? What it means contentwise? And whether it might be due to having very different cluster sizes (reaching from 7 to 32)

Comment: I am voting to leave this open. It's not about lavaan per se, but about a statistical result.